# run a command on a layer above my system

Tags: files, package-management, make

I would like to run a command, `make` in fact, to install something into a "layer".
Afterwards I would like to inspect and pack the files in the layer and gzip them.

I know this is risky since the command may vary it's behaviour, but for this specific case I really need it :D

Is there something around that does that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well-behaved makefiles can be given a "prefix" (a directory) to `make install` files to. Running it without sudo ensures that it doesn't install stuff to system directories.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not behaving fine :(

Comment: Got a link to the thing you're trying to build?

Comment: Sure, https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu

Comment: It has `INSTALL_MOD_PATH` and some other variables that look promising. Try changing them.

Comment: that worked! great!

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use a prefix as HolyBlackCat mentions in a comment. The next best option is to attempt to use a `chroot` envrionment, though this will be more work to accomplish cleanly. I can think of a few other approaches, but they all have far too much work involved to be able to execute them in a reasonable amount of time.